# assigning value to a subscripted element of queryset does not work

Tags: python, mysql, django, apache

EDIT:  as it turns out I don;t believe the migration had anything to do with causing this error.

In the part of the code below where I am selecting aggregate values and assigning those values back to the Usage model I have discovered that the values are not being assigned since I have migrated my application from django dev server to apache.

my debugging output is showing that immediately after those values are assigned, the value is never actually applied to the model instance and when a save is done later on this also reflects that zeros remained in the model instance.

python code

```
    cursor.execute("""select CUSTNBR,
                             FROMDATE,
                             sum(DECTHERMS) as DECTHERMS,
                             max(PRICE) as PRICE,
                             sum(SALESDLRS) as SALESDLRS,
                             sum(MCFS) as MCFS
                    from LQPPNATGAS
                    where CUSTNBR = ? and 
                          FROMDATE <> '20000000' 
                    group by CUSTNBR, FROMDATE """,str(cust_number))


    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row:
        if str(row.FROMDATE)[0:4] >= str(oldest_year): 

            b = Usage.objects.filter(user_id=user_id,from_date=row.FROMDATE)

            b[0].decatherms = row.DECTHERMS
            b[0].price = row.PRICE
            b[0].sales_dollars = row.SALESDLRS
            b[0].mcf = row.MCFS
            b[0].save(update_fields=['decatherms','price','sales_dollars','mcf'])

            print >> sys.stderr ,str(b[0].sales_dollars)+"="+str(row.SALESDLRS)


        row = cursor.fetchone()
```

output in error.log

```
[Thu Aug 29 07:47:15 2013] [error] 0.00=168.22
[Thu Aug 29 07:47:15 2013] [error] 0.00=16.78
[Thu Aug 29 07:47:15 2013] [error] 0.00=1107.88
[Thu Aug 29 07:47:15 2013] [error] 0.00=676.85
[Thu Aug 29 07:47:15 2013] [error] 0.00=28.38
[Thu Aug 29 07:47:15 2013] [error] 0.00=876.94
[Thu Aug 29 07:47:15 2013] [error] 0.00=833.21
[Thu Aug 29 07:47:15 2013] [error] 0.00=26.33
[Thu Aug 29 07:47:15 2013] [error] 0.00=130.85
[Thu Aug 29 07:47:15 2013] [error] 0.00=1058.53
```

Comment: You've run into the fact that [querysets in django are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by assigning the [0] element of the list to another variable, b, and then executing the operations on THAT variable, rather than specifying the [0] at the time I am doing the operations.

revised python code

```
   cursor.execute("""select CUSTNBR,
                             FROMDATE,
                             sum(DECTHERMS) as DECTHERMS,
                             max(PRICE) as PRICE,
                             sum(SALESDLRS) as SALESDLRS,
                             sum(MCFS) as MCFS
                    from LQPPNATGAS
                    where CUSTNBR = ? and 
                          FROMDATE <> '20000000' 
                    group by CUSTNBR, FROMDATE """,str(cust_number))


    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row:
        if str(row.FROMDATE)[0:4] >= str(oldest_year):

            b = Usage.objects.filter(user_id=user_id,from_date=row.FROMDATE)[0]

            print >> sys.stderr , "before b.decatherms="+str(b.decatherms)

            b.decatherms = row.DECTHERMS
            b.price = row.PRICE
            b.sales_dollars = row.SALESDLRS
            b.mcf = row.MCFS
            b.save() #(update_fields=['decatherms','price','sales_dollars','mcf'])

            print >> sys.stderr , "after b.decatherms="+str(b.decatherms)

        row = cursor.fetchone()
```

output in error.log

```
[Fri Aug 30 10:37:28 2013] [error] before b.decatherms=0.0
[Fri Aug 30 10:37:28 2013] [error] after b.decatherms=44.9
[Fri Aug 30 10:37:28 2013] [error] before b.decatherms=0.0
[Fri Aug 30 10:37:28 2013] [error] after b.decatherms=91.1
[Fri Aug 30 10:37:28 2013] [error] before b.decatherms=0.0
[Fri Aug 30 10:37:28 2013] [error] after b.decatherms=3.8
[Fri Aug 30 10:37:28 2013] [error] before b.decatherms=0.0
[Fri Aug 30 10:37:28 2013] [error] after b.decatherms=2.9
[Fri Aug 30 10:37:28 2013] [error] before b.decatherms=0.0
[Fri Aug 30 10:37:28 2013] [error] after b.decatherms=11.8
```